# Error | sudo apt-get update : 404 Not Found [IP: 2604:1380:2000:7501::69 80]

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, server

I have been getting an error when I execute:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Error:

```
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:5 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionic-pgdg InRelease
Ign:6 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt utopic-pgdg InRelease
Hit:7 https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/bionic pgadmin4 InRelease
Err:8 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt utopic-pgdg Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2604:1380:2000:7501::69 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt utopic-pgdg Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I have gone through numerous similar questions, but none of the solutions helped me with this issue. I even replaced the `source.list` and tried to follow all the steps mentioned in these solutions.

As a new user to ubuntu server system, at this point, I am not sure if this is a program installation issue or a system issue.

Server: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Can anyone please assist me with this?

Comment: Have you tried forcing IPv4 using `apt-get -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true update` ?

Comment: I have, this gives me the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you have :

```
Ign:6 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt utopic-pgdg InRelease
```

There is no release for that version. FYI, the Postgres(PGDG) repos only cover LTS releases. You will need to get rid of the Ubuntu Utopic(14.10) repo. It is probably under:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
```

UPDATE. Add further step to find repo.

If that file does not exist try:

`/etc/apt/grep -r -i utopic *`

to find where the repo is listed.

Comment: Thank you for your response! When I try to access this pgdg.list it opens up an empty file for me to write in as there is no file with this name. If I have to get rid of the Utopic repo, is there a way to locate all related repo locations and delete them?

Comment: Note I said probably, did you verify that the file exists in ```sources.list.d```? To try to find the repo listing go to ```/etc/apt/``` and there run  ```grep -r -i utopic *```. That should list the file(s) that have a Utopic repo. They may not all be Postgres related.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that in the text above, the file does not exist there .

Comment: I had an entry in for Utopic in pgsql.list file. I commented the utopic repo description there and this got resolved. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

use the rm function to remove all packages you cannot update, i.e after you check your source list and can confirm packages blocking your updates

or
simply remember that kali cannot update root files that do not follow the HTTPS protocols so if you have packages using only the HTTP protocol you need to simply change these to HTTPS protocols.